# Woocommerce customize content single product

Tags: woocommerce

So I figured finally how to use the woocommerce hooks priorities, 
I'm also using a child theme, but I don't want to just change the priorities of the divs, I want to create my own layout of the single product and echo the price where I want or other stuff...

for example, let's say this is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>content</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <h3>sidebar</h3>
  <div class="price">price</div>
</div>
```

I want to echo the price inside the

```
<div class="price"></div>
```

Can I do that this way? I just don't see why to use other method, the hooks way seems to me not really organized

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use templates instead and customize its content through that. Just copy everything inside `/woocommerce/templates/`, create directory `yourtheme/woocommerce/` and paste it there.

Then assuming that this is a single product, you can do this in your template's `content-single-product.php`:

`<div class="price">$<?php echo $product->price; ?></div>`

Make sure this is anywhere after `global $product;` though. You can check all the data inside the `$product` object by `var_dump`ing it and from there, you can access anything you want about the product.

You can use this in hooks anyway, your choice.

Comment: why did you choose add-to-cart for example? I want to achieve a page which in this page I can decide what to echo, does it make sense? I don't want to start using all of those pages, why should I have for each div a php page?  do you understand what i'm trying to get?

Comment: It wasn't the "add-to-cart" if you look into the template, it's the single product page. WooCommerce just sets the single product pages in a folder called "add-to-cart". Try the snippet I posted on the page you are doing.

The template overriding was just a suggestion, jeez. Tryna help here bruh.

Comment: but it has also a folder named "single-product" and inside of it it has the folder "the add-to-cart" which the add-to-cart is just the button

Comment: Was looking on the wrong project resource, my bad. Check my edit, and don't forget the `global $product;` Also the hook is there I bet you can see the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks where available, this is a good thing if you want your functionality is sort of independent from the theme, but sometimes you just can't hook into some actions (because there isn't any implemented for some of your needs), or you need more control of the layout and all the visual structure, then you can override woocommerce templates in your child theme and do what you want to do.

Check the single-page* templates, maybe that should give you a better idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: how is it related to my question? I know exactly what I need, you just give me irrelevant information

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the answer by myself
If you want to customize the content-single-product with any layout that you want, let's take my example of layout from the question, so you can get rid of the do_action hooks from that page and just insert the functions wherever you want, for example:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <h1><?php woocommerce_template_single_title(); ?></h1>
  <p>content</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <h3>sidebar</h3>
  <div class="price"><?php woocommerce_template_single_price(); ?></div>
</div>
```